# Компонент с передвижной палочкой.

Tags: jquery, html, javascript, css

Полоса от ноля до 100 на которой мозжечок передвижной, и его мышкой можно туда сюда (по горизонтали) по полосе катать, а тебе будет показываться значение, относительно того где он сейчас находится. Вот что мне нужно, можно ли данную вещь найти на JS jQuery, подскажите где, скажите пожалуйста как данный компонент называется правильно. Может есть какие стандартные в html.

Comment: :D Никогда не слышал, чтобы так слайдер называли, это +1

Comment: Те тоже мозжечок понравился? XD

Comment: Мне больше понравился "компонент с передвижной палочкой".
Офтоп: не нашел как тут отправить ЛС, поэтому тут опубликую код для knes:

<pre><code>$(document).mousemove(function(e){
  var img = $('<img class="greenstar" src="greenstar.png" style="top: '+(e.pageY-100)+'px; left: '+(e.pageX-100)+'px" />');
  img.animate({opacity: 0}, 3000, function() {
   $(this).remove();
  });
  
  img.appendTo("body");
});</code></pre>

Comment: В любом случае, спасибо за код. Но он делает не совсем то, что нужно. Мне нужно, чтобы "змейка" исчезала только при движении.

ЛС тут нет.

Comment: Тогда будем флудить ;)

Понятно, просто при движении не получается плавности, из-за цикла. Нужно как-то разделить потоки, создания и дальнейшей обработки. Например, сделать кастомные эвенты и подписать на них все вновь созданные элементы.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно можно. Называется [JQuery-UI slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#rangemin)

Справа - другие примеры со слайдером